# React GraphQL - How to return the results of a Query component as an object to use in React context

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a Query component which gets the information of the a user who has logged in. The query itself works but I am having trouble returning the results of the query as an object which I then want to pass to React.createContext()

I am using Apollo client to make my Query component in my React application.

The following is an example of my current code:

```
 function getUser() {
      return (
        <Query query={query.USER_INFO}>
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <div>Loading</div>;
            if (error) return <div>error</div>;

            const userInfo = {
              name: data.user.name,
              age: data.user.age,
            }

          }}
        </Query>
      );
    }

    //need userInfo object to go here
    export const UserContext = React.createContext(userInfo);
```

How can I get the return of the Query to then use in React.createContext? The reason I want to do it this way is to avoid rewriting this Query in every component where I want info of the user who has logged in.

Comment: What you are looking for might be an HOC, do you absolutely want to use `createContext` or are you opened to different solutions ?

Comment: I second @Treycos here, having used an HOC to handle that exact thing in a current project. That HOC would just wrap that query around your component and pass the resulting data as a prop. The bonus is that Apollo can cache the results so that you don't refire the query over the network constantly.

Comment: could you use redux action, this is a example from react context

Comment: @Treycos I'm absolutely okay using alternatives. I haven't used HOC before so any suggestions are welcomed but I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, to me it seems like you're just missing a return statement:

function getUser() {
      return (
        
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return Loading;
            if (error) return error;

```
        const userInfo = {
          name: data.user.name,
          age: data.user.age,
        }

        return userInfo // ----- this here

      }}
    </Query>
  );
}

//need userInfo object to go here
export const UserContext = React.createContext(userInfo);
```

but i didn't test it out and haven't taken this approach - give it a go see, if it helps